# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'graph'

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to program an application using pygame which can plot lines. The code-snippet is as shown below-

`grapher.py`

```
some code...

x = 500

class graph():
    def drawgrid(step, t = 1):
            for i in range(0, x//step):
                pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 255), (i*step, 0), (i*step, y), t)
                pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 255), (0, i*step), (x, i*step), t)
                pygame.display.update()
```

The `graph.drawgrid()` just draws a grid, with each line spaced out evenly by some pixels(value stored in `step` variable).

When I run `graph.drawgrid()` in the same python file(`grapher.py`), it works as expected.

But now, I want to run the function in a different file(`main.py`). The code snippet is below-

`main.py`

```
import grapher
import pygame

x = 500

draw = grapher.graph()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))

pygame.display.set_caption("Graph")

run = True
while(run):
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    draw.drawgrid(50)

pygame.quit()
```

I call the function, and it gets called, **but** also within that process, the function(`graph.drawgrid()`) when called, throws the following error -

```
   for i in range(0, 500//step):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'graph'
```

And, when I change `for i in range(0, x//step):` to `for i in range(0, x//int(step)):`
It throws this error now-

```
        for i in range(0, 500//int(step)):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'graph'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, can anyone tell where I'm going wrong and the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `self` argument in your drawgrid function.

```
class graph:
def drawgrid(self, step, t = 1):
        for i in range(0, x//step):
            pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 255), (i*step, 0), (i*step, y), t)
            pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 255), (0, i*step), (x, i*step), t)
            pygame.display.update()
```

The first argument of **every** function in your class is always the instance the method is called on. In your case you dont have an argument in the function definition for that, so it gets assigned to step.

Edit: Here's a [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/) explaining it in more detail.

Comment: @NotMyName Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

The class in `grapher.py` and its methods should be declared the following way:

```
class graph:
    def drawgrid(self, step, t = 1):  # add self parameter
```